# Uploading object into transfer accelerated S3 bucket using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am new to AWS.  As I understand, S3 transfer acceleration uses the Cloudfront edges for fastest uploading, but I can't find the proper documentation for PHP API, for uploading object into transfer acceleration enabled bucket. 
My code :

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

 $S3_Client = new S3Client([
'version'     => 'latest',
'region'    =>'ap-south-1',
  'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'Accesskey',
        'secret' => 'Secretkey',
  ],
 'endpoint' => 'http://my_bucket_name.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com'
]);

$bucket = 'my_bucket_name';
$key = 'EC2.pdf';
$SourceFile = '/path/to/the/file/EC2.pdf';


$put = $S3_Client->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $key,
    'SourceFile' => $SourceFile
]);
```

I am getting the following error

```
The authorization header is malformed;
the region 'ap-south-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-1'
```

but my bucket is located in us-east-1 , when I change the region as

```
us-east-1
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The specified bucket does not exist
```

Comment: Instead of `endpoint => ...`, please try 
`'use_accelerate_endpoint' => True` in the client constructor and see what that does.  You will also need to set the region to the bucket's region, since that is used for authentication.

Comment: Yes its working ... ! But, what is the use of  `endpoint` @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `endpoint => ...`, pass `'use_accelerate_endpoint' => True` to the [constructor](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#___construct).

There are a number of different rules that come into play when building a request to send to S3.  The `endpoint` option provides a *service* endpoint, rather than a *bucket* endpoint, and is mostly useful for non-standard configurations.

Comment: when enable transfer acceleration to a bucket , the endpoint appears  ... what is the use of that .. they are not used  in accelerate a speed ?

Comment: @ArunKumar you are referring to the endpoint that appears in the console?  Yes, that is the endpoint used for acceleration, but if you are using one of the SDKs, that isn't information that you need, because enabling acceleration in the SDK generates the correct endpoint automatically.  It is always `https://${bucket}.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com` (or, newly-introduced, `https://${bucket}.s3-accelerate.dualstack.amazonaws.com` for IPv6) so the SDKs can calculate the endpoint automatically using only the bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to this discussion: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2774

Try the following solution - 
"I had same issue, i had created the bucket previously and deleted it. I changed the name and it applied no problem."

Comment: I changed the bucket and enable transfer acceleration , Its not working for above code

Comment: Sorry, though it was the region bug problem.

Comment: Found https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1372 AND https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/S3/S3Client.php#L196. Apparently you can just add  use_accelerate_endpoint => true to the  settings and remove the endpoint setting. Then your queries will be automatically routed to the accelerator endpoint.